# Inserting the data at a time in 3 tables using an array into Postgresql database

Tags: sql, postgresql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I have to insert the data at a time in 3 tables into PostgreSQL database.

I have to insert data  into first and Second table is directly.

But The third table which i received data as array and inserted into 3rd table as same.

Is data inserting as array into PostgreSQL available or possible?

If it possible how can I insert can some correct me
**How can i do the same mechanism with Wso2 DSS 3.0.1.**

My  query is

```
   with first_insert as (insert into sample(name,age)
                     values(?,?)
                  RETURNING id
),
second_insert as (insert into sample1(empid,desig)
                 values((select id from first_insert),?)
                 RETURNING userid
)

insert into sample2(offid,details)
          values((select userid from second_insert),?)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I understood your question exactly, but at least you could use `insert into ... select`:

```
with cte_first_insert as
(
    insert into sample1(name, age)
    values('John', 25)
    returning id
), cte_second_insert as (
    insert into sample2(empid, desig)
    select id, 1 from cte_first_insert
    returning userid
)
insert into sample3(offid, details)
select userid, 'test'
from cte_second_insert;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1038a/2)</kbd>**

Comment: Hi Roman,I edited my question,please look into once, i need to store the data as array directly into 3rd table.

Comment: Could you provide desired result from my sqlfiddle example?

Comment: For third table sample3 ,i am receiving the array type as {1,2,3}, now i am going to store this array directly into database, or if possible i need to split the values and stored into respected  columns. please guide me if possible how i can insert.